# Looping through slides with Cycle2, but not all slides

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

I have a slideshow of 6 slides, and I'm trying to cycle through the first **3** slides, while skipping slides **4-6**, but when a user clicks on a button for slides 4, 5, or 6, I want to show those slides.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Rvn4/1/

Some behaviors I need to achieve:

- Automatically cycle through `DIVs` **A B C** continuously.
- When `DIVs` **Z Y or X** are clicked, go to *and* stop on respective slide **Z Y or X**.
- After, if the user clicks on slides for **A B or C**, go back to doing the first step continuously.
- *Note: I don't want to create any pagers for slides **Z Y and X**. (I can hide them simply with CSS, but I'd rather do it programmatically.*

---

```
<div id="custom-pager"></div>

<div class="mySlideshows" 
     data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true">

    <div data-cycle-pager-title="Nav Button A"><p>Slide A</p></div>

    <div data-cycle-pager-title="Nav Button B"><p>Slide B</p></div>

    <div data-cycle-pager-title="Nav Button C"><p>Slide C</p></div>


    <div><span>Slide X</span></div>
    <div><span>Slide Y</span></div>
    <div><span>Slide Z</span></div>    

</div>
```

---

I tried to make the JSFiddle basic, but if you need context for what I'm trying to accomplish in production, here's the site so far. http://s35290.gridserver.com/JWA/

The top nav (experience, service, and results) are the main slides I want to cycle (ABC) continuously. 
But if a user clicks on a person, I want to show content associated with them (their contact information, in this case, 6 slides.)

Comment: Is this functionality even possible with cycle2?

Comment: I would think it would be possible: You would probably need to use the `cycle-before` event, detect when an auto-cycle (and not click event) has occurred, and stop the cycle to the unwanted slide and "restart" the index of the slide back to the first. I don't see a means to do this automatically with settings, though.

Comment: So I'll have to add Jquery code mixed in?

Comment: Unless someone else comes up with some configuration incantation I don't see (possible), it would seem you'd need to customize the behavior with custom coding.

Comment: I got it working. Had to use jQuery to do all the leg work; put my non-cycling slides outside the slideshow, hiding any visible slides on clicks, pausing slideshow, etc.